# How to get your network ip

Tags: networking

I am on a network with PPPoE connection for internet acces.I want to find out my network ipv4.
Example:

-on Windows 7 I can see both my PPPoE's connection ip and local network ip, either from properties of the connection, either from cmd with `ipconfig` command

-on ubuntu I can only see the PPPoE's ip

I cam across this problem after trying to lookup another ubuntu pc on the network.

How can I check my Local area connection(Windows terms) ip and/or how to see the other ubuntu pc from my network?

---

If I connect to my DSL account I can see my ip(ipv4 and 6) from my DSL connection but not my eth0 ip.

If I connect to my Wired connection I can see my ip from my eth0 connection but after that I cannot connect to the internet.

I cannot have both?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but you can see your IP address using `ifconfig`.

Comment: I can see my PPPoE(DSL connection) ip, but I need my network(eth0) ip(ipv4 not ipv6).

Comment: that's why you use ifconfig....

Comment: actually if you would've looked on this page you would've guessed already that I know about the command ifconfig

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the top panel of Unity go to the Network Icon (Network Manager) and select **Connection Information**

[image]

You will see all the information including the IP (IPv4 and IPv6) of any device connected. In this case it is only showing one device since I have only one connected, but if I had multiple ones it would show each one on a different tab:

[image]

For the terminal way you can do like Mitch mentions. Open a terminal and type `ifconfig` which will show you several network devices like the following:

[image]

In your case, instead of seeing **wlan0** like in my image, you will see something like **ppp0**. If you want to see specific information about your PPP connection then do something like this: `ifconfig ppp0`.

Looking at your images we have the following:

[image]

This image shows the IP you are receiving from Internet (From outside of your LAN network). In this case it is the **10.40.26.151**

[image]

This image shows the IP you are receiving from LAN (From inside of your LAN network). In this case it is the **192.168.2.160** and the Router or Server IP that is assigning you that IP is **192.168.2.1**.

Now looking at both images I see you are using **eth0** for both cases. If this is the same computer then I recommend connecting ppp0 to another network card and eth0 to the LAN if you want to have both types of connection. You can only have one type of connection per network device.

Comment: look at my comment on the upper answer

Comment: @adi updated to explain your images. Also I would like to know if you are disconnecting the ppp connection to connect the LAN one and vice versa. I ask since I see you are using the same network device for both.

Comment: yes Luis,that is what I did.

Comment: @adi Then you need another network card. One network card for you LAN connection and the other one for your PPP connection. This way you get on the same computer the IPv4 address for your LAN and the IP address for your PPP internet connection.If you already have 2 network cards, then can you please tell me all the network cards mentioned when using ifconfig. For example I have eth0 and wlan0. I will also suggest to connect you PPP connection to your router, the one that is assigning you the 192.168.2.x IP. That way, the router will give you internet and LAN connection in one network device.

Comment: I cannot acces the router since I'm on an university campus network and we do not have acces to router management.I have both lan and wireless cards.

Comment: @adi Then I suggest to buy an additional network card for your PC (Am assuming it is a Desktop computer). For now, there is no way to connect to different networks on the same network card.

Comment: no,it's a laptop,so there is no way to acces my network and internet on same device?that's a downside to ubuntu really.

Answer (score 5):

You can do so by clicking on the network icon on the top right bar, and choose edit connections.  Once the new window opens, click on the **Edit** button, and that will take you to the network properties page, you can then click on IPv4 settings to see the info.

OR

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below:

```
ifconfig
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: So help me understand this, If I connect to my dsl account I have internet connection but no ipv4 on eth0, and if I connect to my "Wired connection" I have ipv4 on eth0 and no internet connection.

Comment: My ips with eth0 and ppp0 connections http://imageshack.us/g/1/10076463/

Answer (score 4):

`ifconfig` [is being deprecated](https://serverfault.com/questions/458628/should-i-quit-using-ifconfig). It is suggested to use the `ip` command.

For example:

[image]

Also, if you are behind NAT you may wish to use an external service to find your public IP address. `curl icanhazip.com` will return that for you.